# Restrict UIScrollView srollable area

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I'm working with a UIScrollView to display a large document, I want to restrict the area that the user can view somehow. I have almost achieved the desired result with the following code:

```
[childView setFrame:CGRectMake(offsetX, offsetY, contentWidth, contentHeight)];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)];
```

With `offsetX` and `offsetY` being negative numbers to move the child view outside of the scrollview area. This works perfectly at zoom level 1.0 but not at any other zoom levels. I have implemented `- (void)setZoomScale:(float)zoomScale` like this:

```
- (void)setZoomScale:(float)zoomScale {
    [super setZoomScale:zoomScale];
    [childView setFrame:CGRectMake(offsetX * zoomScale, offsetY * zoomScale, contentWidth, contentHeight)];
}
```

But this doesn't work, the offset gradually gets further out the more the view is zoomed. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you could fix the minimum and maximum zoom scale to 1.

However, it works for me if I set the contentSize in scrollViewDidZoom:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024*scrollView.zoomScale, 1024*scrollView.zoomScale)];
}
```

btw, make sure you turn bounces off to check accurately:

```
scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Seems to work perfectly in scrollViewDidZoom: but not in setZoomScale: